# cleaner way to unlink a File::Temp file?

Tags: perl, file, temp

I'm currently doing this

```
my $tmpf = File::Temp->new;
$tmpf->unlink_on_destroy(1);
```

but it seems like this could be cleaner.. something like

```
my $tmpf = File::Temp->new({unlink => 1});
```

is something like the latter possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also set this flag in the constructor:

```
my $tmp = File::Temp->new( UNLINK => 1, SUFFIX => '.dat' );
```

But it is unnecessary. From the perldoc [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/~tjenness/File-Temp-0.22/Temp.pm#OBJECT-ORIENTED_INTERFACE):

> by default the object is constructed
>   as if tempfile was called without
>   options, but with the additional
>   behaviour that the temporary file is
>   removed by the object destructor if
>   UNLINK is set to true (the default).

Comment: I must have missed that in the docs, I originally used the functional interface, which must not set this? because it was leaving the files behind.